# .NET Core 5.0 - Angular 9 - how to get HTTP return code while maintaining MVC/json mapping?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

context: Angular 9 requesting data to a .NET Core 5.0 API

I try to observe the http return code, so I added **{observe: "response"}**

```js
getLoggedUserInfos(singlePost:SinglePost) {
    return this.http.post<UserFetch>(this.appConfigService.getConfig()["apiUrl"] + 'api/Users/loggedUserInfos',singlePost,{observe: "response"});
}
```

but since then, my code does not compile anymore

```js
this.getLoggedUserInfos(singlePost).subscribe((userFetch:UserFetch)=>{
...
```

No overload matches this call.

How can I solve this?

Thanks for your help

[edit]

map and catchError seems not defined

```
getLoggedUserInfos(singlePost:SinglePost) {
    return this.http.post<UserFetch>(this.appConfigService.getConfig()["apiUrl"] + 'api/Users/loggedUserInfos',singlePost,{observe: "response"})
    .pipe(
        map(response => response as UserFetch),
        catchError((err) => {
           console.error(err);
           throw err;
        })
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIRC, there is no overload with type assertion *and* `{observe: "response"}`. Try to assert using RxJS `map` operator

```js
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

getLoggedUserInfos(singlePost:SinglePost): Observable<UserFetch> {
  return this.http.post(
    this.appConfigService.getConfig()["apiUrl"] + 'api/Users/loggedUserInfos',
    singlePost,
    { observe: "response" }
  ).pipe(
    map(response => response as UserFetch) // <-- possibly error prone
  );
}
```

And since you're getting the whole response now, the return variable from the `map` operator must be some property of the `response` variable.

**Edit**: Add imports.

Comment: I tried your solution but map seems not defined, I'll mod my question with my code

Comment: ok it needed this : import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: @phil123456: I've included the import statement in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see what exactly your goal is, if you want to handle error codes differently there are better options, than looking at the status code via the response yourself (https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling).

You get a compilation error, because the post method returns `HttpResponse<UserFetch>` so when subscribing, it is not of Type `UserFetch`, but instead `HttpResponse<UserFetch>`. When you really want to look at the status code than you can do it there.

```js
this.getLoggedUserInfos(singlePost).subscribe(response => {
  console.log(response.status);
  const userFetch = response.body;
});
```

I would recommend using `catchError`, there are very good examples.

Comment: I need the http code, not only the errors

Comment: It is like literally the code example provided